# Using remove-if-not with &key parameters

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following code, which is supposed to be a higher-order function that filters elements based on the  `&key`  arguments entered (in this case `:year`, `:month` and `:type`.

```
   (defun filter-by (&key year month type)
   "Remove members of the list not matching the given year and/or month and/or type, returns a
   function that takes the list"
     (lambda (lst)
       (remove-if-not #'(lambda (element)
         (when year
           (equalp (local-time:timestamp-year (get-record-date element))
                   year)))
         (when month
           (equalp (local-time:timestamp-month (get-record-date element))
                   month)))
         (when type
           (equalp (get-type element)
                   type))))
       lst)))
```

The problem is that unless **all** the keyword arguments are used, it will always return `nil`, I'm guessing because of how the `when` form behaves inside `remove-if-not`.

Is there anyway to make this work without resorting to multiple `cond` statements? The problem with `cond` is that I would have to *specifically* write down all the possible combinations of arguments used, which is ok for 3 arguments but it makes it very hard to extend if in the future I would like to use other keywords for filtering.

Comment: The code does not make much sense, because the parentheses are not set correctly. You might want to indent the function correctly and then fix the syntax errors.

Comment: The problem is that you're not combining the results of the `equalp` forms, so in fact only the last one counts.  Use `or` around the `when` forms.

Comment: why is there that outer lambda in the function? This function returns function instead of filtered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common Lisp's keyword parameters have a special syntax that lets you tell
whether a parameter was supplied or not.  I think you should be able to use
this to accomplish what you want.

Here is a working example, albeit with a slightly different data representation
since I don't have your definitions of `local-time` and `get-record-date`.  You
should be able to easily adapt this to your code.

```
(defun my-filter-by (lst &key
                         (year  nil year-p)   ;; nil is the default
                         (month nil month-p)  ;; year-p/month-p/day-p say whether
                         (day   nil day-p))   ;; the argument was supplied
  (remove-if-not
   (lambda (element)
     (let* ((year-okp (or (not year-p)
                          (equal year (cdr (assoc :year element)))))
            (month-okp (or (not month-p)
                           (equal month (cdr (assoc :month element)))))
            (day-okp (or (not day-p)
                         (equal day (cdr (assoc :day element)))))
            (all-okp (and year-okp month-okp day-okp)))
       all-okp))
   lst))
```

And some examples:

```
(defparameter *lst* '(((:year . 2000) (:month . :may) (:day . 17))
                      ((:year . 2000) (:month . :may) (:day . 18))
                      ((:year . 2001) (:month . :aug) (:day . 2))
                      ((:year . 2002) (:month . :jan) (:day . 5))))


(my-filter-by *lst*) ;; keeps everything
(my-filter-by *lst* :year 2000) ;; everything from 2000
(my-filter-by *lst* :year 2000 :day 17) ;; only 2000 / may 17
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. I didn't think about using predicates like that.